# nextjs and prisma application getting error when publish to vercel

Tags: next.js, prisma, vercel

im using nextjs with prisma ,and my application is published on vercel, and today i changed my prisma Schema and generate and migrated the changes and for some reason when im in devlopment the prisma controllers works perfect,
but when i upload my application to vercel im getting error on build, and I'm pretty sure the problem is that vercel doesn't recognize the changes I made to the schema bec the error im getting is realted to the changes that i did to the schema.

i tried to generate and migrated again and stil it dosent worked.
and this is the error im getting:

Type error: Type '{ todoTypeTitle: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Enumerable | undefined'.
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'todoTypeTitle' does not exist in type 'Enumerable'.

Answer (score 1):

Your build script should include `npx prisma generate` command to ensure that your schema changes are correctly reflected in the generated Prisma Client.

Here's an [example](https://github.com/prisma/deployment-example-vercel/blob/main/package.json#L13) that demonstrates how `npx prisma generate` command can be a part of build script. In the example `migrate deploy` is also the part of the script, you can omit it if you are not using Prisma Migrate.